# MYSQL query with leading zero returns the same result as without

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple MySQL table with an Auto-increment `id` as the primary key.

Supposed I want to select the first `id`, I run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '1'
```

I tried by mistake the following query and it returned the same result although it should return empty result.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '01'
```

This leads to duplicate URLs on my site and many problems like invalid file references and such. Is this a bug?

Comment: Does this really work?  It doesn't say that `1` is not recognized as a column?  That is how backticks normally work in MySQL.

Comment: `id` is of integer type and both `'1'` and `'01'` are implicitly converted to int during the comparison operation.

Comment: _[42S22][1054] Unknown column '01' in 'where clause'_

Comment: @GordonLinoff  `1` is a value for the column. Not the column itself. The problem is that MYSQL is treating `1` as `01` which is kind of stupid considering It's the primary key

Comment: What is the type of the primary key?

Comment: Exactly `SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Is there any MYSQL solution for this?

Comment: OK, then your key is an integer, hence '1' and '01' are exactly the same as far as your key is concerned.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos ok what data type should I use to avoid this?

Comment: Sanitize the data in your application.

Comment: In my opinion this works great. 1 and 01 are the same number, so who would even *want* them to be treated differently? Moreover an ID is just an ID in a database. It has no meaning aside from relating records. So you shouldn't even care whether the ID is 1 or 9183654783894. It just doesn't matter. If it does matter to you, then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: As you mention that you build URLs from the ID, and an URL is a string, I would recommend you introduced a unique string key in your table - or build your URL on formatted numeric IDs (such as 12 digits with leading zeros).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If id is a integer, it is as expected.

Implicit type conversion to compatible type is done here.

```
mysql> select 1 = '01', 1 = '1', '1' = '01';
+----------+---------+------------+
| 1 = '01' | 1 = '1' | '1' = '01' |
+----------+---------+------------+
|        1 |       1 |          0 |
+----------+---------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Ok what data type should I use to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Use string type, like CHAR, VARCHAR and etc. @MichaelSamuel

Comment: Your data type is appropriate.  Your problems are not sql related.  They are being caused by your php code somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, the reason for the result you get is *implicit type conversion*: the '1' or '01' is converted to an integer so that it matches the type of `id` field *before* the comparison takes place.

A quick and dirty solution around this problem is to `CAST` the field, like:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable 
WHERE CAST(id AS CHAR(10)) = '1'
```

Of course the best approach would be to sanitize your data of your application.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b0ef2/1)